# Grabbing R^2 from linear model in R

Tags: r

After running something like:

```
mod.1<-lm(z~x+y)
```

I know I can do summary(mod.1) and see the $R^2$ value. I'm wondering how I might grab it from mod.1, sort of like grabbing the coefficients with mod.1$coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mod.1 = lm(c(1,2,3)~ c(1,2.3,3.4))
summary(mod.1)$r.squared
```

Comment: How can you write out the list of numbers available using summary(mod.1)$?

Comment: equivalently, `?summary.lm`

Answer (score 4):

R-squared is actually not an element of the `lm` object itself, but of `summary(mod.1)`. That is, if you type `str(summary(mod.1))` you will see that the summary is itself a list (with a special `print` method) and that one of those list items is R-squared.

However, for programmatic use it's inefficient to calculate the entire summary just to extract one element. Rolling your own extractor function would lead to faster code in general, especially if you call `lm` with the argument `y = TRUE`. Then R-squared would just be `1 - sum(mod.1$residuals^2)/sum((mod.1$y - mean(mod.1$y))^2)`.